# How to write xPath for the child element from the parent element in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, xpath, protractor

I'm working on Protractor testing where I found the one element by its class. Now, I want to find it's sibling based on the element I found earlier.

As shown in the below code, I had found the span by using "element(by.css(locate))". Now based on this element I want to click on the "a" link. There are so many same spans like this on a page with the different class name. So, I want to click to the specific "a" tag based on a selected class span.

```
<div>
<span class="123456">
</span>
<a ng-click="openLink()" class="ng-binding">temp</a>

</div>
```

I expect to click on a "a" element but I can't use "element(by.css('[ng-click="openlink"]'))" because there are so many "a" tag with same ng-click on a page.

I tried below code but didn't work.

```
        locate = ".123456";
        var icon = element(by.css(locate));
        element(by.xpath(icon + ' > a')).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
var ele = element(by.cssContainingText('div > a', 'temp'));

ele.click();
```

Comment: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .123456 > a)

Comment: This is the result when I didn't write await. But, If I write await then it is giving me "Unexpected Identifier" error.

Comment: Can you check the question again please?

Comment: @Virus Are you trying to click the tag `a`?

Comment: Yes I want to click element a.

Comment: It won't work because "a" is not the child element of the span. It is a sibling element of a span

Comment: It will also not work as the page have many divs with the <a> tag so my only option is to get the benefit of span class.

Comment: @Virus Could your share surrounding htlm element to make the parent unique

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no unique parent element. Only unique sibling span element is there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using following.

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@class="123456"]/following-sibling::a')).click();
```

It passed but not clicking the element.

Comment: This looks like the correct locator to me, are you awaiting that command?

Comment: I also tried doing "var sgpt = require('sg-protractor-tools');
        sgpt.scroll.scrollTo(element(by.css(locate)));" but still no luck

Comment: @Virus , you probably need to wait until found link bacame clickable

Comment: The easiest way to check if you locator is correct when using xpaths is simply to open chrome dev tools to do a find on the source code, using the xpath directly [example](https://imgur.com/a/ERjUsu6). Your locator is correct so it must be another issue. And to answer your question you should only need to await the click if your control flow is disabled, I just noticed you mentioned it in another comment so wanted to double check.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you the code for finding the element by link text in protractor test cases.

Here is code example:

```
var myElement = element(by.css('span.123456 + a'));
myElement.click();
```

Above code finds the link with 'temp" text and then clicks on it.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Vikas ... I'm sorry but there are many <a> tags with the temp value on the page.

Comment: I have updated the answer.[Virus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10953978/virus), Try once

Comment: Yeah, this one should work. `+` is used for finding the following sibling. if you want to achieve the same with XPath use `//*[@class="123456"]/following-sibling::a`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `xpath` and click on the element.

```
element(by.xpath('//a[@class="ng-binding"][text()="temp"]')).click();
```

Comment: No element find using locator